# What is a data structure which is unordered and allows repetitions called?

Tags: data-structures, set

Is there any "formal name" for data a structure with the following features:

- set/group which allows repetitions
- unordered (order has no significance)

For example, a list is an ordered set/group with repetitions.

In the set `{2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,7,6,5,6}` there is no significance to the order so the an efficient way to implement is set with 2-d arrays `{[2,4],[3,4],[4,3],[7,1],[6,2],[5,1]}`.

I am asking if there is any formal name to it ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "set/group with returns"? Do you mean "repetitions"? And by "but there is no value to the order", do you mean that there is no significance to the order of elements (unordered)?

Comment: for example {2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,7,6,5,6}
there is no value to the order so the best way to implement is set with 2d array {[2,4],[3,4],[4,3],[7,1],[6,2],[5,1]} i am asking if there is any fomral name to it  ?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "best". It is efficient, under some assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably referring to a [Multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

It is a set that allows multiple instances of an element.